# Tomcat 7 Spring App IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jpa-2.0, tomcat7

Not sure who is responsible for this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

This error occurs whey I try to run my spring web app in Debug mode from the IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 (my project is maven format project).

When running the same application from the standalone Tomcat 7 Web server (put war into webapps folder) it works fine. Also from mvn clean install t7:run-forked application also works fine.

My app is Spring JPA application using Hibernate as JPA provider, c3p0 is used for connection pooling (switched to it from bonecp, thought that the bonecp was the cause of this error, but it is still reproducible with c3p0 too), Spring TomcatInstrumentationLoading is used for JPA support on Tomcat.

My OS is Debian, Linux.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should be enough to make it work:

[image: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m]

**VM options** field is set in the [Tomcat Run/Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html) to

`-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Comment: Cool!! This solved the problem for me. Thanks soo much.

My problem was occurring when running unit tests, but I was able to apply the same concept to my unit test run configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Set VM arguments to allocate more space for your program

like

```
-Xms128m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: You should explain those arguments. The first two ones don't have anything to do with the permgen space, and 8 GBs is a lot more than typical dev machines can support.